# Why was my question migrated to ELL?

Tags: discussion, questions

My question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/285777/what-is-the-difference-between-they-and-it-for-people-especially-for-those has moved to ELL. I actually wanted to know more about third person pronouns in English, if possible linguistic and historical knowledge, rather than focusing on gender issues, and I got help from the answers.

According to [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), Avoid migrating answered questions. I think the migration goes directly against this. At the time of migration, I had already adopted one answer, and the question had several other answers.

I would like to send it back to ELU. What should I do?

Comment: All the answers appear to have been deleted, regardless of their scores. Why is this?

Comment: @Davislor [They should be here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/568283).

Answer (score 2):

[Done](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/568283), albeit not without some hiccups.

Comment: Thank you for switching it back and I upvoted yonks ago... but how come the number of views has dropped to 700, when I'm pretty sure the Q accumulated 2k before the migration?

Comment: @Mari-LouA They might be part of the hiccups tchrist mentioned. I remember discussing migration-rejection some time ago, and found that rejecting a migration tends to be messy. The question can end up in limbo at both ends. Getting the question back more-or-less intact is already an improvement on that.

Comment: @Lawrence Some more hiccoughs on the way soon. Stack Exchange has been bought for 1.8 billion dollars. Read all about it!!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh dear. Who bought it?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365050/what-does-the-recent-sale-of-stack-exchange-mean-for-the-community  some company called *Prosus*